# I tried to run my app but this error occurs like the method EE was called as null

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJmYu.png)I tried to run my app but this error occurs like the method EE was called as null
any one help please

code:

```
 DateFormat.EE().format(DateTime.now())
                            ,Text(
                              DateFormat('EE').format(
                                DateTime.now().add(
                                  Duration(days: f),
                                ),
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if EE is a valid method.. Please check this list

```dart
ICU Name                   Skeleton
 --------                   --------
 DAY                          d
 ABBR_WEEKDAY                 E
 WEEKDAY                      EEEE
 ABBR_STANDALONE_MONTH        LLL
 STANDALONE_MONTH             LLLL
 NUM_MONTH                    M
 NUM_MONTH_DAY                Md
 NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY        MEd
 ABBR_MONTH                   MMM
 ABBR_MONTH_DAY               MMMd
 ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       MMMEd
 MONTH                        MMMM
 MONTH_DAY                    MMMMd
 MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY            MMMMEEEEd
 ABBR_QUARTER                 QQQ
 QUARTER                      QQQQ
 YEAR                         y
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH               yM
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_DAY           yMd
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY   yMEd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH              yMMM
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_DAY          yMMMd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY  yMMMEd
 YEAR_MONTH                   yMMMM
 YEAR_MONTH_DAY               yMMMMd
 YEAR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       yMMMMEEEEd
 YEAR_ABBR_QUARTER            yQQQ
 YEAR_QUARTER                 yQQQQ
 HOUR24                       H
 HOUR24_MINUTE                Hm
 HOUR24_MINUTE_SECOND         Hms
 HOUR                         j
 HOUR_MINUTE                  jm
 HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND           jms
 HOUR_MINUTE_GENERIC_TZ       jmv   (not yet implemented)
 HOUR_MINUTE_TZ               jmz   (not yet implemented)
 HOUR_GENERIC_TZ              jv    (not yet implemented)
 HOUR_TZ                      jz    (not yet implemented)
 MINUTE                       m
 MINUTE_SECOND                ms
 SECOND                       s
```

You can use any of these Skeleton as method like

```
DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now())
```

Make sure to import intl

You can do this instead

```
DateFormat('EEEE').format(date).subString(0,2)
```

Comment: how to import intl for this code help please

Comment: DateFormat('EEEE').format(date).subString(0,2);

Comment: You can import dependency from https://pub.dev/packages/intl official documentation

Comment: I added dependency but not imported

Comment: You need to import that package too